# Returning results from a third Android activity to the first Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, mobile

I have my main activity which calls a second activity via `startActivityForResults`. My second activity then calls a third activity via `startActivityForResults`, but in this process my second activity `finishes`. Now the third activity will `finish`, but will need to send back a result code via `setResult`. My first activity has the `onActivityResult` method in place, but never receives anything or is never called.

I'm having trouble managing this issue between the three activities. What is the simplest way to take care of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest may be the use of a Singleton class.

```
public class ResultHolder {
  private String result; // Whichever result code you need to persist
  public String getResult() {return result;}
  public void setResult(String result) {this.result = result;}

  private static final ResultHolder holder = new ResultHolder();
  public static ResultHolder getInstance() {return holder;}
}
```

In your activity that **posts** the result code:

```
ResultHolder.getInstance.setResult(whateverResultCode);
```

In your activity that **receives** the result code:

```
String resultCode = ResultHolder.getInstance.getResult();
```

Hope this helps.